# I have a problem with my UITextField simulator keyboard which would not pop up again for any user input once I run the app

Tags: swift, uitextfield

when I ran my Xcode and went to type "Vatican City" in it , I typed Vatican using simulator keyboard and mistakingly typed City with my laptop keyboard.

once I pressed my laptop key , the simulator keyboard disappeared from the screen.

Now whenever I run my app and press on the UITextField, I do not get my simulator keyboard to pop up to take user input but it take input via my laptop keyboard
The properties in the attributes pane have been the same and nothing has been changed manually by me for my simulator to function like this. what should I do to get the simulator keyboard to pop up again when I want to give some user input?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzL9c.jpg)

Comment: Try pressing Cmd+Shift+K in the simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enabling your software keyboard:

[image]

Shortcut keys: Cmd+Shift+K